# get HTTPS header in python

Tags: python, https, hotmail, setcookie

i'm dealing with HTTPS and i want to get HTTP header for live.com

```
import urllib2

try:
    email="HelloWorld1234560@hotmail.com"
    response = urllib2.urlopen("https://signup.live.com/checkavail.aspx?chkavail="+email+"&tk=1258056184535&ru=http%3a%2f%2fmail.live.com%2f%3frru%3dinbox&wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1258055283&rver=6.0.5285.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx&lc=1036&id=64855&bk=1258055288&rollrs=12&lic=1")
    print 'response headers: "%s"' % response.info()
except IOError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'code'): # HTTPError
        print 'http error code: ', e.code
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'): # URLError
        print "can't connect, reason: ", e.reason
    else:
        raise
```

so i don't want all the information from headers i just want `Set-Cookie` information

if you asking what is script do : it's for checking if email avilable to use in hotmail by get the amount from this viralbe `CheckAvail=`

## after edit

thanks for help .. after fixing get only `Set-Cookie` i got problem it's when i get cookie not get `CheckAvil=` i got a lot information without `CheckAvil= after open it in browser and  open the source i got it !! see the picture [image]

Comment: @senderle - I think the question is how to get a specific header from `response.info()` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object returned by `response.info()` is an instance of [`mimetools.Message`](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetools.html#mimetools.Message) (as described by the [`urllib2` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)), which is a subclass of [`rfc822.Message`](http://docs.python.org/library/rfc822.html#rfc822.Message), which has a `getheader()` method.

So you can do the following:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("...")
print response.info().getheader("Set-Cookie") # get the value of the Set-Cookie header
```

However, if you are checking for mail, I would recommend you to use POP3 or IMAP if available (Python comes with modules for both).

Comment: Liquid_Fire sir give me the idea for checking avilabe mails via `POP3` or `IMAP` it's look like great idea

Comment: Have a look at the docs for the [`poplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html) and [`imaplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html) modules (they both have examples near the bottom), and look in the Windows Live help for POP3 or IMAP configuration settings which will give you the server, port and other settings you'll need to provide to the library to connect.

Comment: guys why the `CheckAvail=` not in the header !! i have code by perl and in the header i got `CheckAvail= ?!`

Answer (score 0):

It's because 'Httponly' in your http response, which meant, because of the specifications, only http connection can view.